# Convert IIS CA Certificate to Ubuntu Haproxy cerificate

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, haproxy, windows-server-2012-r2

Alright, I setup a simple Windows 2012 R2 RDs server aio farm with Web Access, everything works fine internally if I access the server directly (https: // rdsiisserver/RDWeb/). I created a Ubuntu HAProxy (https: // haproxy-server) and have it forwarding https directly to the RDS IIS server. It works too, the main IIS front page is loaded, but I can not access the Web Access page (".../RDWeb/"). I get the following error in chrome if I try to access RDWeb:

> This webpage has a redirect loop

IE displays the following error:

> > There is a problem with this website's security certificate.
> >         We recommend that you close this webpage and do not continue to this website.
>
> ```
> Click here to close this webpage.  
> Continue to this website (not recommended).
> ```

I press "Continue", and the page fails with "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

There is a CA certificate on the RDS IIS server, everything was secure and works perfectly if I access the RDWeb IIS server directly. When I added the  haproxy I exported the pfx certificate and I had to convert it to pem with openssl on the ubuntu haproxy server:

> openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -out cert.pem -nodes

I imported the GoDaddy certificate and added it to my haproxy cfg. It seems to work, as I can access the rds iis main webpage securely with https... but not RDWeb sub page.

Question is, is it the certificate? I understand the GoDaddy certs can be problematic and I have tried converting the cert several ways but the above conversion was the only one that actually worked for me without HAProxy failing to start.

Do i need the same certificate on both servers? I would like to use https internally and externally.

Comment: To debug SSL issues, use `openssl s_client -connect <addr>:<port>` and compare the results. The same certificate should be presented from all locations. - Note that the SSL handshake will also fail if the cert is correct, but you don't reach the site through the CN or a SAN.

Comment: "This webpage has a redirect loop". I think this is totally unrelated to the certificate itself.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what is the **exact** error message in Internet Explorer, regarding the certificate? Click on the certificate button next to the web address bar.

Comment: I agree with Daniel; the redirect is almost certainly not caused by your certificate issue. You should post your haproxy config for further help with that.